# flutter iOS app crashes when trying to upload image using camera inside Webview

Tags: ios, flutter, webview

I am creating a flutter app using webview_flutter plugin, everything is working fine. In the website, there is a form in which users can upload images(that asks to choose weather to use Camera or Album to choose image). When I tap on Camera the app crashes.

Comment: Please share some code or crash log to trace what exact issue you are getting. Also Have you added camera access key in plist file

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Crashes happen because your app needs to request a permission from user to access camera or photos library (depending on what user picks). But in order to make such request you need to provide a message with description on why do you need this permission. Such description should be added into `Info.plist` file located in `ios/Runner` folder of the project.

For the case you described with picking image from camera or photos library you need to add the following 2 keys with descriptions:

```
<key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
<string>Your description on why app needs access to camera</string>

<key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
<string>Your description on why app needs access to photos library</string>
```

Here is information about mentioned keys in the official docs:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/nscamerausagedescription
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/nsphotolibraryusagedescription

One more case with webview when you would need to have `NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription` or `NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription` in project's `Info.plist` file is to avoid crashes when user tries to download image via `Save to photos` context menu item. Such context menu appears when user long presses on some image on a web page.

The difference between 2 keys above is in fact that `NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription` allows your app to only write (download) images to photos library, not read them, so it is more preferable way if you only want to let image downloads.
Here is info about this key: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/nsphotolibraryaddusagedescription

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the latest version of webview_flutter? I did a `flutter pub upgrade` and added

```
<key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
<string>Add image to profile</string>
```

to `ios/Runner/Info.plist`.